# local variable 'ebytexts' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def run(self):
        for i, data in self.data.iterrows():
            
            if data.crossover == 'bullish close' and i > 62:
                for position in self.positions:
                    if position.status == 'open':
                        position.close_position(data.time, data.close)
            
            if data.crossover == 'bearish close' and i > 62:
                for position in self.positions:
                    if position.status == 'open':
                        position.close_position(data.time, data.close)
            
            if data.crossover == 'bullish crossover'and i > 62 :
                **if position.status != 'open':**
                    self.add_position(Position(data.time, data.close, 'buy', self.volume, 0, 0))
            
            if data.crossover == 'bearish crossover'and i > 62:
                self.add_position(Position(data.time, data.close, 'sell', self.volume, 0, 0))
        
        return self.get_positions_df()
```

Добавляю строчку в код:

```
if position.status != 'open':
```

Выходит

```
`local variable 'ebytexts' referenced before assignment`
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос **полный стек-трейс ошибки**, все его строки. По пересказу ошибок (наверняка не точному) тут не гадают, извините.